# Can't find the result of $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac 1 {n(n+1)(n+2)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I can't find the result of:

> $$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac 1 {n(n+1)(n+2)}$$

From the p-criterion the series converges,but what do we do to find the result?

Comment: it telescopes !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Hint : 
>   $$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}$$
>   $$\begin {align}
> = \frac {1}{2}. \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac {1}{n(n+1)}-
>       \frac {1}{(n+2)(n+1)}\right)
> =\frac {1}{2}
> \end {align}$$